# Style indent background color of a QML TreeView

Tags: qt, treeview, qml

I want to change indentation background color as shown in following image:
[image]

Up to now, I have something like:

```
Component
{
  id: fileItem

  Rectangle
  {
    color: "blue"
  }
}

TreeView {
    id: view
    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.margins: 2 * 12 + row.height
    model: fileSystemModel
    rootIndex: rootPathIndex
    selection: sel
    alternatingRowColors: false
    style: TreeViewStyle {
      branchDelegate: Rectangle {
        width: 16
        height: 16
        color: styleData.isExpanded ? "green" : "red"
      }
      frame: Rectangle {border {color: "blue"}}
      backgroundColor: "blue"
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        title: "Name"
        role: "fileName"
        resizable: true
        delegate: fileItem
    }

    onActivated:
    {
      var url = fileSystemModel.data(index, FileSystemModel.UrlStringRole)
      Qt.openUrlExternally(url)
    }
}
```

It is based on [Qt Quick Controls - File System Browser Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-filesystembrowser-example.html)

Comment: Add [`rowDelegate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-treeview.html#rowDelegate-prop) to your `TreeView`. For example, `rowDelegate: Rectangle { color: "pink" }`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Make it an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To customize each row in a `TreeView`, override [`rowDelegate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-treeview.html#rowDelegate-prop) property. For example,

```
TreeView {
    rowDelegate: Rectangle { color: "pink" }

    style: TreeViewStyle {
      branchDelegate: Rectangle {
        width: 16; height: 16
        color: styleData.isExpanded ? "green" : "red"
    }
    frame: Rectangle {border {color: "blue"}}
    backgroundColor: "blue"
    //...
}
```